# Col of Concat-ed cell causes error 13 when using Application.Index() in a diff Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the Concatenation code Below, it works wonderfully.

The problem is that the column of concatenated cells throws a error  `"Type mismatch` in a different Macro that matches columns (I have used the matching macro extensively) even though the concatenated column is not one of the matching columns of the matching macro.

If I delete the column of concatenated cells the matching Macro work fine.

The error ocrurs at this point in the matching macro

```
wsPB.Range("A" & j).Resize(1, sLC).Offset(1, 10).Value = Application.Index(arrS, i, 0)
```

I am pretty sure the problem is:

```
Application.Index(arrS, i, 0)
```

Is their a way to get the Concatenate code below to not produce the `Type mismatch" when it encounters:

```
Application.Index(arrS, i, 0)
```

I do not see anything odd about the way the ConCat code post back the concatenated cells to the page with
    .Value = a

any help or insight is greatly appriciated

Thank you

```
Sub ConCat()
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, i As Long

Set rng = Range("B2,A2,D2,N2,L2")

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    ReDim a(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To 2)
    a(1, 1) = .Cells(1, 1).Value
    a(1, 2) = "Concat"
    For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
        a(i, 1) = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        For Each r In rng
            If .Cells(i, r.Column) <> "" Then
                a(i, 2) = a(i, 2) & IIf(a(i, 2) = "", "", "|") & _
                .Cells(i, r.Column).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    With .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 2)
        .Value = a
    End With
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that some of the cells in the sheet were over the 254 char limit and this was causing the error 13 thrown by `Application.Index(arrS, i, 0)` in the maching function and had nothing to do with the ConCat code

The fix was to re-write the Matching function without using `Application.Index(arrS, i, 0)`